# Is it possible hide or to disable "Uninstall" option for extension on Fennec addons list?

Tags: installation, add-on, fennec

I have Fennec bootstrap extension. I integrate it into `fennec.apk` by puting the extension into the distribution folder at

> objdir/dist/bin/distribution/extentions

Everything works perfect.

The extension can be found in the add-ons section:

> fennec menu->tools->Add-ons.

Is it possible hide it from this list, or to disable the `Uninstall` option?